# how to determine which dataset is being used for a specific variable?

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i would like to know how can i determine whether [FirstName] on the report is being pulled from dataset1 or dataset2???

[image]

Comment: In single table matrix you can refer to only one dataset. So if you know that in particular table you refer to dataset1 you are sure that the first name is from dataset1. You can add for example hidden textbox above the table with the dataset name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on Konza's comment: The tablix (or table) is connected to one dataset. Right click in the upper left corner of the gray border of the selected tablix to show the Tablix Properties dialog. Or look in the Visual Studio Properties pane for the properties of your tablix.

The property will be listed as "Dataset name" in the dialog and as "DataSetName" in the properties pane.